# regarding replacing a column following a given pattern

Tags: excel

I have a excel file, in which one column has the data set such as following:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
100.txt
20.txt
30.txt
```

I have to replace this column with the following one by removing all of the .txt from each cell

```
1
2
3
100
20
30
```

How to do that in Excel? Thanks.

Comment: This would have been a good one for SuperUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user785099,
You may find it useful to use the "Text to Columns" feature, or possibly "Search & Replace".

**Text to Columns**
Select the column in question. Under the `Data` tab find `Text to Columns`, choose this, and under `Original Data Type` choose `Delimited`. Select `Next`. Then under `Delimiter` specify `Other` and insert a `.` in the corresponding field and choose `Finish`.
This will result in two columns, you can just delete the one populated with `txt`

**Search & Replace**
Highlight the column, or cells
Use the keyboard shortcut `ctrl+h` or graphically select `Home` -> `Find & Select` -> `Replace ...` to bring up the Find & Replace dialog box

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `SUBSTITUTE` function.  In an adjacent cell, enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".txt", "")
```

and drag and copy as necessary.